# html - Why my three buttons are vertical instead of horizontal?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the confusing I caused. I did not paste my code because it is part of my big assignment. Also, I do not sure what parts of code cause the problem. So I paste the parts of the code that contains these three buttons

I want to make these three button display horizontally( Which I think is default). However, the website shows them vertically. Could anyone tell me the reason behind it? what should I do to make them horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


</div>

<div id="Comparing Energy" class="tab">
<h3 style="color:darkblue;"> Units for comparing energy (Gasoline and Enthanol) </h3>
<p class="Sansserif">BTU stands for British Thermal Unit, which is a unit of energy consumed by or delivered to a building. A BTU is defined as the amount of energy required to increase the temperature of 1 pound of water by 1 degree Fahrenheit, at normal atmospheric pressure. Energy consumption is expressed in BTU to allow for consumption comparisons among fuels that are measured in different units. [think-energy.net]</p>

<pre class="Sansserif"><span style="font-family:sans-serif;">Below are some BTU content of common energy units:
     1 gallon of heating oil = 138,500 BTU
     1 cubic foot of natural gas = 1,032 BTU
     1 gallon of propane = 91,333 BTU
</span></pre>

<p class="Sansserif"><b>Let's compare the different energy amount between burn gasoline and ethanol</b></p>


<button onclick="expandable()"><b>Calculate</b></button>

<p id="inputinfo" class="Sansserif" style="display:none"> By entering the amount of gasoline, this program will perform the appropriate calculations and display the equivalent amount of energy it produces in BTU. Please input a number: </p>

<input id="btu" style="display:none" onkeyup="myDefault()">
<button id="energybutton" onclick="energy()" style="display:none;"><b>Submit</b></button>
<button id="wizardbutton" onclick="wizard()" style="display:none;"><b>Wizard</b></button>
<button id="slidebutton" onclick="simple()" style="display: none;"><b>Simple</b></button>

<p id="numb2" style="display:none">
<input type=radio name=myradio onclick=document.getElementById("btu").value=1>Small<br>
<input type=radio name=myradio onclick=document.getElementById("btu").value=4>Medium<br>
<input type=radio name=myradio onclick=document.getElementById("btu").value=6>Large<br>
</p>

<p id="BTU"></p>
<p id="defaultValue"></p>

<script>

function energy() {
    var x, text;

    // Get the value of the input field with id="numb"
    x = document.getElementById('btu').value;

    j = x * 115000
    t = x*76700
    text = " "+x+" gallon of gas produces "+j+" BTU "+x+" gallon of ethanol produces "+t+" BTU";
    document.getElementById("BTU").innerHTML = text;
}

function myDefault() {
   var x = document.getElementById('btu').value;

    if (x <= 10)
        document.getElementById("defaultValue").innerHTML = "A typical small one is 5";
    else if ((x > 10) && (x <= 20))
        document.getElementById("defaultValue").innerHTML = "A typical medium one is 15";
    else if (x > 20)
        document.getElementById("defaultValue").innerHTML = "A typical large one is 25";
    else 
        document.getElementById("defaultValue").innerHTML = " ";  
}

function wizard() {
    var v = prompt("By entering the amount of gasoline, this program will perform the appropriate calculations and display the equivalent amount of energy it produces in BTU. Please input a number: ");

    if (v != null) {
        document.getElementById('btu').value=v;
    }
}


function simple() {
    document.getElementById('btu').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('numb2').style.display='block';
}

function expandable() {
    document.getElementById('inputinfo').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('btu').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('energybutton').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('wizardbutton').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('slidebutton').style.display='block';

}

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe other CSS style attributes?

Comment: Why do so many people ask questions with some or no code? It isn't helpful.

Comment: How does the code that show them (change their display property) look like?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my question again and include more codes. Hope it is more clearly this time.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say without the rest of your code present, but probably some other CSS is causing the buttons to render as `block` elements instead of their standard `inline` display mode.

You could write the following CSS rule:

```
#energybutton, #wizardbutton, #slidebutton {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

And it would probably solve it, but that seems a little ugly and the `!important` is undoubtedly overkill.  If you'd like to provide some more context I or someone else could provide a more elegant answer, but my hunch is this might work for you.

Edit:
Seeing your exit with more code the issue is obvious- in your `expandable` method you are changing the buttons to `display: block` -- this is why they are displaying with breaks between then. Instead, set the `display` property to `inline` or `inline-block` to achieve the desired effect.

Incidentally, it might be more robust to hide/show the buttons not directly by directly manipulating styles in JS, but instead by adding/removing a class with the desired associated CSS set.

Answer (score 3):

```
display: inline-block;
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change the display of your buttons to 'inline' instead of 'none'.

Answer (score 0):

First I would place all the buttons within a div so you can property CSS them.

```
<div class="title_of_div">
    <button id="energybutton" onclick="energy()" style="display:none"><b>Submit</b></button>
    <button id="wizardbutton" onclick="wizard()" style="display:none"><b>Wizard</b></button>
    <button id="slidebutton" onclick="simple()" style="display: none"><b>Simple</b></button>
</div>
```

Then your CSS would look something like this:

```
.title_of_div a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px; <!-- You enter your own height -->
    width: 100px; <!-- You enter your own width -->
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: why you selecting '<a>' however child elements are '<button>' so you should select '.title_of_div button'